# Garbage value in rapid json AddMember

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

```
{
    std::string result;
    RapidJSON::Value json;
    json.SetObject();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        RapidJSON::Value data;
        data.SetObject();
        for(auto it = HashMap.begin(); it != HashMap.end(); it++)
        {
            RapidJSON::Value arrObj;
            arrObj.SetObject();
            for(auto it2 = it->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); it2++)
            {
                arrObj.AddMember(RapidJSON::StringRef(it2->first.c_str()), RapidJSON::StringRef(it2->second.c_str()), d.GetAllocator());
            }
            data.AddMember(RapidJSON::StringRef(it->first.c_str()), RapidJSON::Value(arrObj, d.GetAllocator()).Move(), d.GetAllocator());

        }
        json.AddMember(RapidJSON::StringRef(str.c_str()), RapidJSON::Value(data, d.GetAllocator()).Move(), d.GetAllocator());
    }
    
cleanup:
    retJson.AddToJson(RapidJSON::StringRef("STATUS"), json);
    result = retJson.ToString();
}
```

I am using this method to convert a map to a json, but after each iteration of the outer for loop the value in the json value changes, the value assigned during the previous iteration becomes garbage values
Can't find any solution,
I have tried using creating a new Value and using the Move method, but that also didn't help

Comment: I'm not sure, I only just started reading about this API, but I stringly suspect that you need to create a new `arrObj` and a new `data` each time you add to your json, instead of reusing a single objects.

Comment: @john I have also tried that,
It doen't work either
I am creating arrObj inside the for loop so it should be created for each object right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use stringRef, instead create a copy of the strings in both arrObj, data member
Sample code

```
RapidJSON::Value key(it2->first.c_str(), d.GetAllocator());
arrObj.AddMember(key, it2->second, d.GetAllocator());
```